# Transactional Email in Send Preview

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm building an Email that will be send as Transactional, so there will be no Profile Center link.

When I try to do a Send Preview it fails the validation and won't preview. In the past I've had Support remove the Profile Center Link Validation.

This seems like a poor solution since this effects all other emails. The only other thing I can think of is to add a Profile Center link with CSS to hide it. This seems stupid too.

Am I missing a simpler solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can work around the check by hiding the links:

```
%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%%
<a href="%%profile_center_url%%">Base Profile/Preference Center</a>
<br><a href="%%subscription_center_url%%">Base Subscription Center</a>
<br><a href="%%unsub_center_url%%">Base One-Click Unsubscribe</a>
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Seems so easy when I see it. :-)